# Sublime Text 4 Borró el contenido de mi archivo PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext

Tengo sublime text 4 con el package PHPTools instalado, y estaba modificando un archivo php bastante extenso (unas 22,000 lineas de código), cuando modifique un texto automaticamente me elimino el código y me apareció este mensaje.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /Users/userA/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/PHPTools/php.tools/codeFormatter.php on line 1060

Necesito ayuda, no he podido recuperar mi archivo!

Comment: Sublime text no lo borró solo no tiene la capacidad de memoria para procesarlo, intenta abrirlo con otro editor como VS Code y verifica que aun tenga la información

Comment: Intente abrir el archivo con otro editor y solo me sale el mensaje "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ...", ¿como recuperar el contenido?

Comment: Entonces lo que paso fue que te mando ese mensaje y guardaste tu script por lo cual te reemplazo el contenido, creo que para eso busca un respaldo, no creo que lo recuperes su ya está guardado con esa información

Comment: Un archivo php con 22k de lineas ?? cuanto pesa dicho archivo ?

Comment: @Excorpion está ligero pesa alrededor de los 710kb,

Comment: @MRDev ya lo suponia, dejare de usar Sublime Text. Se supone que un editor no deberia cambiar o modificar el contenido de un archivo a menos que uno mismo lo haga